# Converge of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k x^k $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

For what values ​​of x the sum converges  and what is the limit when $n \rightarrow \infty$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k x^k $

My work:

First i try to calculate the interval and radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k x^k $ by using the ratio test:

$$p(x) =\lim_{k \to \infty} \left| \frac{(k+1) x^{k+1}}{kx^k} \right| = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{\left( k+1 \right)}{k}x\right|$$

here i stuck can you help me please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there.

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{(k+1)}{k} x \right|= \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{k+1}{k}\right|.|x| = |x|,$$
now, for convergence we need ...?

To find the limit, you should follow the hint given by T.Bongers.

In a bit more detail, we know that for $|x|<1$ we have

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \dots$$

Now differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ (valid inside the circle of convergence):

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + \dots$$

so

$$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} = x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + 4x^4 + \dots$$

Comment: $|x| \leq 1$ then sum converge?

Comment: Yes - now can you find an expression for the limit following the hint?

Comment: @Knight: the inequality must be strict.

Comment: Ah yes - you need $|x| < 1$ - sorry.

Comment: The terms of a geometric series form a geometric progression, meaning that the ratio of successive terms in the series is constant but when he said differentiate i need differentiate all the expression?

Comment: Just take the series $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots$ and differentiate with respect to $x$. That will (almost) get you to the final answer.

Comment: sorry for my stupid question but i need to differentiate 1 /1-x or the power serie $ k x^k $

Comment: You need to differentiate both sides of what I wrote in my last comment.

Comment: i got 1 / x^2 -2x + 1 = 1+2x+3x^2

Answer (score 3):

For $\left| x \right|<1$ yu have the *absolute convergent* series

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

Because of the absolute convergence you are allowd to interchange summation with differentiation and you get

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dx}x^k  = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k\cdot x^{k-1} $$

On the other hand you have

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{1}{\left(x-1\right)^2}$$

Thus it holds
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k\cdot x^{k-1} = \frac{1}{\left(x-1\right)^2}$$

Multiplying with x gives you
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k\cdot x^{k} = \frac{x}{\left(x-1\right)^2}$$

Note that the first summand on the left side is zero for $k=0$ so you have finally

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k\cdot x^{k} = \frac{x}{\left(x-1\right)^2}$$

Comment: You canexchagen differentiation and summation in this particular case, but are you sure that absolute convergence is enough to justify it ? See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611471/termwise-differentiation-for-absolutely-convergent-series) for a discussion of this issue.