# Show that $(\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kz^k)'\leq\frac1{(1-|z|)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $S_n(z):=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kz^k$ be the sequence of partial sums of a power series, such that $|a_k|\leq1$. Show that for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|<1$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$ exists (i.e. $S_n$ converges).
>   Also show that the following holds: $$|S_n'(z)|\leq\dfrac{1}{(1-|z|)^2}$$

One can show the first part by finding that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_k|}\leq 1$ and hence the radius of convergence of the series that corresponds to $S_n$ is greater or equal to $1$, giving us the first part.
The only thing I could come up with for the second part is that $S_n'(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\,a_k\,z^{k-1}$ but didn't get any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $|z|<1$ we have

$|S_n'(z)| \le \sum_{k=0}^{n}k|a_k||z|^{k-1} \le  \sum_{k=0}^{n}k |z|^{k-1} \le \sum_{k=0}^{ \infty}k |z|^{k-1}= \frac{1}{(1-|z|)^2}.$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but how did you come up with the last equality?

Comment: user. Have a look:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629589/converge-of-the-sum-sum-k-1n-k-xk